# How to show that some nested radicals simplify to other

Tags: nested-radicals

Show that $\sqrt{8}\cdot\sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}}=2\cdot\sqrt{11}-2\cdot\sqrt{7}$

I have tried multiplying the radicals but that didn't work.

The resulting radicals do not add up or get subtracted.

I have tried taking commons also but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf {HINT:}$ Try to show that
$$\big( \sqrt 8 \cdot \sqrt{9-\sqrt{77}} \big)^2 =\big(2\sqrt{11}-2\sqrt7\big)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

multiply both side of the fraction to $\sqrt {2}$
$$\sqrt { 8 } \cdot \sqrt { 9-\sqrt { 77 }  } =\sqrt { 8 } \frac { \sqrt { 18-2\sqrt { 77 }  }  }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } =\sqrt { 8 } \frac { \sqrt { { \left( \sqrt { 7 } -\sqrt { 11 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } =\frac { \sqrt { 8 }  }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \left| \sqrt { 7 } -\sqrt { 11 }  \right| =2\left( \sqrt { 11 } -\sqrt { 7 }  \right) $$